# Get the actual file extension using NiFi

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi, file-extension

I am using Apache NiFi to ingest data from Azure Storage. Now, the file I want to a huge file (100+ GB) read can have any extension and I want to read the file's header to get its actual extension.

I found `python-magic` package which uses `libmagic` to read the file's header to fetch the extension, but this requires the file to be present locally.

The NiFi pipeline to ingest the data looks like this
[image]

I need a way to get the file extension in this NiFi pipeline. Is there a way to read the file's header from the Content Repo? If yes, how do we do it? FlowFile has only the metadata which says the `content-type` as `text/plain` for a CSV.

Comment: You are using groovy scripts to fetch file. Just add there fire lines to add own attributes.

Comment: groovy scripts are to update the status of the processors in Redis.

Comment: Then please clarify the question. Where you are taking flow file, is file name attribute is present after you received it...

Comment: I can always get the file extension from the name which I don't want to do. I want to get the file extension by reading its header.

Comment: what does it mean "header"? could you give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a generic 'header' that *all* files have that gives you it's "real" extension. A file is just a collection of bits, and we sometimes choose to give extensions/headers/footers/etc so that we know how to interpret those bits.

We tend to add that 'type' information in two ways, via a file extension e.g. `.mp4` and/or via some metadata that accompanies the file - this is sometimes a header, which is sometimes plaintext and easily readible, but this is not always true. Additioanlly, it is up to the user and/or the application to set this information, and up the user and/or application to read it - neither of which are a given.

If you do not trust that the file has the proper extension applied (e.g. `video.txt` when it's actually an mp4) then you could also try to interrogate the metadata that is held in Azure Blob Storage (ContentType) and see what that says - however, this is also up to the user/application to set when the file is uploaded to ABS, so there is no guarantee that it is any more accurate than the file extension.

`text/plain` is not *invalid* for a plaintext CSV, as CSVs are just formatted plaintext - similar to JSON. However, you can be *more specific* and use e.g. `text/csv` for CSV and `application/json` for JSON.

NiFi does have [IndentifyMimeType](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.IdentifyMimeType/index.html) which can try to work it out for you by interrogating the file, but it is more complex that just accessing some 'header'. This processor uses [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/1.22/detection.html#Mime_Magic_Detection) for the detection, and adds a `mime.type` attribute to the FlowFile.

If your file is some kind of custom format, then this processor likely won't help you. If you know your files have a specific header, then you'll need to provide more information for your exact situation.